# Program type already present:a.a.a.b

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, startapp

after adding the startapp implementation i got the following error after sync and rebuild:

> Program type already present: a.a.a.b Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program
>   type already present: a.a.a.b, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.9.3'
}
```

have any idea? thanks in advance..

Comment: I think this activity can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837344/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-app-backstackrecord

Comment: i've checked before and checked now again but i couldn't find which group and module must be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

this activity helped me very much :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292583/3035333

i moved startapp implementation from app/gradle to project/gradle. so it worked.